# ChineseLunisolarCalendar to GregorianCalendar invalid date

Tags: c#, calendar

I try to calculate the "Mid-Autumn Festival" public holiday in china for any year. But the date is for some years invalid, i use the documentation of [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_China) (*15th day of 8th Lunisolar month*)

```
var chineseCalendar = new ChineseLunisolarCalendar();
var midAutumnFestival = chineseCalendar.ToDateTime(year, 8, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

The date in the year 2017 and 2020 are invalid, what is wrong?

```
Calculated Date | Correct Date
2020.09.02      | 2020.10.01
2017.09.05      | 2017.10.04
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2017 and 2020 have leap months.

https://www.chinesegenderchart.info/leapmonth.php

Leap 6th month for 2017

Leap 4th month for 2020

Now look into below documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.chineselunisolarcalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> A leap month can occur after any month in a year. For example, the
>   GetMonth method returns a number between 1 and 13 that indicates the
>   month associated with a specified date. If there is a leap month
>   between the eighth and ninth months of the year, the GetMonth method
>   returns 8 for the eighth month, 9 for the leap eighth month, and 10
>   for the ninth month.

Based on above documentation, when you query for 8th month in 2017 and 2020, you have to ask for 9 as month which represents 8th month.

something like below:

```
var chineseCalendar = new ChineseLunisolarCalendar();
var midAutumnFestival = chineseCalendar.ToDateTime(year, 9, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```